# Redirecting with yes > /dev/null & top

Tags: command-line

I am following a tutorial

```
yes > /dev/null & top
```

Output
[image]

I do not understand what this line is doing.
Top only
[image]

It seems that I have one process less.
Why?

Comment: Have you tried running it? (It’s safe.)

Comment: Yes,but I can not copy the output. What is the difference with top only?

Comment: You have one process less, because you didn't run `yes`? What did you expect?

Comment: What is the question? Run `yes` alone and you'll see what it's doing. You can stop it with Ctrl+c.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The significant part is the first line in the list of processes show by `top`. When you run

```
yes > /dev/null & top
```

you end up with a `yes` process using all the CPU it can get. The command above is equivalent to

```
yes > /dev/null &
top
```

because `&` not only puts a process in the background, it also acts as a command separator. So you’re running `yes` in the background, redirected to `/dev/null`, and `top`.

`yes` with no arguments outputs `y` followed by a newline continuously; since it’s redirected to `/dev/null` it can do so as fast as possible.